# follower/following in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-3.0

We are designing a twitter like follower/following in Cassandra, and found something similar
[image]

from here https://www.slideshare.net/jaykumarpatel/cassandra-at-ebay-13920376/13-Data_Model_simplified_13

so I think **ItemLike** is a table?
itemid1=>(userid1, userid2...) is a row in the table?
what do you think is the `create table` of this ItemLike table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, `ItemLike` is a table**

Schema of the ItemLike table will be Like :

```
CREATE TABLE itemlike(
    itemid bigint,
    userid bigint,
    timeuuid timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY(itemid, userid)
);
```

The picture of the slide is the internal structure of the above table.

[image]

Let's insert some data :

```
 itemid | userid | timeuuid
--------+--------+--------------------------------------
      2 |    100 | f172e3c0-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb
      2 |    103 | eaf31240-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb
      1 |    100 | d92f7e90-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb
```

Internally cassandra will store the data like below :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    |             100:timeuuid              |            103:timeuuid                | 
|    +---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------|
|2   | f172e3c0-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb  |  eaf31240-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

---------------------------------------------|
|    |             100:timeuuid              |
|    +---------------------------------------|
|1   | d92f7e90-67a6-11e7-8e08-371a840aa4bb  |
---------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: so I just `insert into itemlike(itemid, userid) values(100, 1000)`, `insert into itemlike(itemid, userid) values(100, 1001)` and on? I thought the picture is something like ``insert into itemlike(itemid, userid1, userid2...) values(100, 1000, 1001, 1002.....)``

Comment: yes,you just insert with `insert into itemlike(itemid, userid) values(100, 1000)`. internally cassandra store data  like the slide image